# "g++ is not a full path" when compiling a program using Google Test

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I am trying to compile with g++ a program that uses Google Test as a submodule. Here is what I tried:

```
git init testgoogletest
cd testgoogletest
git submodule add https://github.com/google/googletest.git
```

Then, I created a CMakeLists.txt containing:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5.1)
project(try_googletest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)

set(VARIABLE_INCLUDE_DIR "${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include" "${gmock_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
add_subdirectory(../googletest gtest)

target_include_directories(gmock_main SYSTEM BEFORE INTERFACE
    "${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include" "${gmock_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

add_executable(my_executable test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_executable PRIVATE gmock_main)
```

And a file named test.cpp containing:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

TEST(SimpleTest, works) {
    EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}
```

Then, I ran the commands:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

And I got the following fatal error:

```
CMake Error at (personal path)/googletest/CMakeLists.txt:7 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    g++

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

Yet, when I run `which g++`, I get `/usr/bin/g++` which means that the compiler name is in the PATH and that CMake should find it. I even tried the following:

- Removing Google Test and replacing test.cpp with an empty main, which perfectly works and means that the problem is about Google Test
- Replacing in CMakeLists.txt `g++` with `/usr/bin/g++`, which produces an infinitely large periodic output when running `cmake ..`

My questions are:

- Why am I getting those errors?
- Does there exist a solution or do I really need to forget about CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER and use CXX instead?

Comment: Works for me. Is the line `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)` real or you have updated it in your question?

Comment: @S.M. Do all of the alternatives work for you? I confirm that I wrote here exactly what I did.

Comment: I did not check other alternatives. Similar error comes in the most cases  if "g++" would be returned from another code or function and would contain line end. This would be solved by using `string(STRIP, value, variable)`.

Answer (score 1):

I followed your steps. We indeed get an infinite loop, and the following output:

```
You have changed variables that require your cache to be deleted.
Configure will be re-run and you may have to reset some variables.
The following variables have changed:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER= /usr/bin/c++
```

Changing the `set` in `CMakeLists.txt` file in the following way appears to fix this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/c++)
```

Comment: This works but does it use the `g++` compiler? And is it platform-dependent? And where do those errors come from?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347726/why-does-cmake-refuse-to-use-a-non-default-compiler